# List comprehension as substitute for reduce() in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

The following python tutorial says that:

> List comprehension is a complete substitute for the lambda function as well as the functions `map()`, `filter()` and `reduce()`.
>
> http://python-course.eu/python3_list_comprehension.php

However, it does not mention an example how a list comprehension can substitute a `reduce()` and I can't think of an example how it should be possible.

Can please someone explain how to achieve a reduce-like functionality with list comprehension or confirm that it isn't possible?

Comment: "Removed reduce(). Use functools.reduce() if you really need it; however, 99 percent of the time an explicit for loop is more readable." ([source](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins))

Comment: I would recommend finding a better source for your learning. The quoted page says "Generator Comprehension", which is not the right term and the explanation given is also not that satisfactory.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ideally, list comprehension is to create a new list. Quoting [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

> **List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists.** Common applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of some operations applied to each member of another sequence or iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a certain condition.

whereas `reduce` is used to reduce an iterable to a single value. Quoting [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce),

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to **reduce the sequence to a single value**.

So, list comprehension cannot be used as a drop-in replacement for `reduce`.

Answer (score 5):

I was surprised at first to find that Guido van Rossum, creator of Python, was against `reduce`. His reasoning was that beyond summing, multiplying, and-ing, and or-ing, using `reduce` yields an unreadable solution that is better suited by a function which iterates through and updates an accumulator. His article on the matter is [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). So no, there isn't a list comprehension alternative to `reduce`, instead the "pythonic" way is to implement an accumulating function the old fashioned way:

Instead of:

`out = reduce((lambda x,y: x*y),[1,2,3])`

Use:

```
def prod(myList):
    out = 1
    for el in myList:
        out *= el
    return out
```

Of course nothing stops you from continuing to use `reduce` (python 2) or `functools.reduce` (python 3)

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions are supposed to return *lists*. If your reduce is supposed to return a list, then yes, you can replace it with a list comprehension.

But this is no obstacle to providing "reduce-like functionality". Python lists can contain any object. If you'll accept your result contained in a single-item list, then there is a `[...][0]` list comprehension form that can replace any `reduce()` whatsoever.

This should be obvious, but that form is

```
[x for x in [reduce(function, sequence, initial)]][0]
```

for some binary `function` and and some iterable `sequence` and some `initial` value. Or, if you want the `initial` from the first of the iterable,

```
[x for x in [reduce(function, sequence)]][0]
```

---

Arguably, the above is cheating, and also pointless, since you could just use `reduce` without the comprehension. So let's try it without `reduce`.

```
[stack.append(function(stack.pop(), e)) or stack[0]
 for stack in ([initial],)
 for e in sequence][-1]
```

This produces a list of all the intermediate values, and we want the last one. `[-1]` is just as easy as `[0]`. We need an accumulator to reduce, but can't use assignment statements in a comprehension, hence the `stack` (which is just a list), but we could have used many other data structures here. The `.append()` always returns `None`, so we use `or stack[0]` to put the value so far in the resulting list.

It's a little more difficult without `initial`,

```
[stack.append(function(stack.pop(), e)) or stack[0]
 for it in [iter(sequence)]
 for stack in [[next(it)]]
 for e in it][-1]
```

Really, you might as well use a `for` statement at this point.

---

But this takes up memory for the list of intermediate values. For a very long sequence, that might be a problem. But we can avoid that too by using generator expressions.

Doing this is tricky, so let's start with an easier example and work up to it.

```
stack = [initial]
[stack.append(function(stack.pop(), e)) for e in sequence]
stack.pop()  # returns the answer
```

It computes the answer, but also creates a useless list of `None`s. We can avoid that by converting it to a generator expression inside a list comprehension.

```
stack = [initial]
[_ for _s in (stack.append(function(stack.pop(), e)) or ()
              for e in sequence)
 for _ in _s]
stack.pop()
```

The list comprehension exhausts the generator that updates the stack, but returns an empty list itself. This is possible because the inner loop always has zero iterations, because `_s` is always an empty tuple.

We can move the `stack.pop()` inside if the last `_s` has one element. It doesn't matter what that element is though. So we chain on a `[None]` as the final `_s`.

```
from itertools import chain
stack = [initial]
[stack.pop()
 for _s in chain((stack.append(function(stack.pop(), e)) or ()
                  for e in sequence),
                 [[None]])
 for _ in _s][0]
```

Again, we have a single-item list comprehension. We can also implement `chain` as a generator expression. And you've already seen how to move the `stack` variable inside using a single-item list.

```
[stack.pop()
 for stack in [[initial]]
 for _s in (
         x
         for xs in [
                 (stack.append(function(stack.pop(), e)) or ()
                  for e in sequence),
                 [[None]],
         ]
         for x in xs)
 for _ in _s][0]
```

And we can also get the initial from the sequence for the two-argument `reduce`.

```
[stack.pop()
 for it in [iter(sequence)]
 for stack in [[next(it)]]
 for _s in (
         x
         for xs in [
                 (stack.append(function(stack.pop(), e)) or ()
                  for e in it),
                 [[None]],
         ]
         for x in xs)
 for _ in _s][0]
```

This is insane. But it works. So yes, it's *possible* to get "reduce-like functionality" with comprehensions. That doesn't mean you *should*. Seven `for`s is too hard!

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish something like a reduce with a comprehension by using a couple of helper functions that I've named `last` and `cofold`:

```
>>> last(r(a+b) for a, b, r in cofold(range(10)))
45
```

This is functionally equivalent to

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, range(10))
45
```

Note that unlike `reduce()` the comprehension didn't use a `lambda`.

The trick is to use a generator with a callback to "return" the result of the operator. `cofold` is the [corecursive dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion) of the reduce (or fold) function.

```
_sentinel = object()
def cofold(it, initial=_sentinel):
    if initial is _sentinel:
        it = iter(it)
        accumulator = next(it)
    else:
        accumulator = initial
    def callback(result):
        nonlocal accumulator 
        accumulator = result
        return result
    for element in it:
        yield accumulator, element, callback
```

Here's `cofold` in a list comprehension.

```
>>> [r(a+b) for a, b, r in cofold(range(10))]
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
```

The elements represent each step in the dual reduction. The last one is our answer. The `last` function is trivial.

```
def last(it):
    for e in it:
        pass
    return e
```

Unlike `reduce`, `cofold` is a lazy generator, so it can safely act on infinite iterables when used in a generator expression.

```
>>> from itertools import islice, count
>>> lazy_results = (r(a+b) for a, b, r in cofold(count()))
>>> [*islice(lazy_results, 0, 9)]
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
>>> next(lazy_results)
55
>>> next(lazy_results)
66
```