# How to turn this code into a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Easy question, i'm trying to become fluent with LCs and coding 'blackjack' for a project. Here's a sample of the code:

```
# define globals for cards
SUITS = ['C', 'S', 'H', 'D']
RANKS = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
VALUES = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}

hand = ['C4','HK'] #4 of spades and the king of hearts should total 14

total = 0
for card in hand:
    if card[-1] in VALUES:
        total += VALUES[card[-1]]
print total

total = 0
print [total+VALUES[card[-1]] for card in hand if card[-1] in VALUES]
```

You can see the working for loop (which returns 14) and my attempt at the LC implementation. It returns a list [4, 10]

How can i make it return the sum of elements in that list ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34586159/1903116) might be of some help

Answer (score 5):

```
print sum(VALUES[card[-1]] for card in hand if card[-1] in VALUES)
```

Comment: You don't need to buffer the comprehension in a list; `sum(VALUES[card[-1]] for ...)` is sufficient.